# Count repeated values of a dimension without having it in the table

Tags: business-objects, webi

I need to count the number of people who repeat an option, but without having the "Name" dimension in the table that I am going to display, only the "Option" dimension and an added counter for each option, this is an example of the starting data:

```
I have:                                         

ID  Name  Option                                    
 
1    AA    cccc   
2    AA    bbbb   
3    AA    bbbb   
4    AA    bbbb   
5    BB    bbbb   
6    BB    cccc   
7    CC    kkkk   
8    CC    bbbb   
9    CC    kkkk   
10   DD    bbbb   
11   DD    bbbb   
12   HH    bbbb   
13   HH    kkkk   
14   HH    bbbb
```

```
I want:

Option   Number of names with repeated option

 bbbb                   3
 kkkk                   1
```

I have tried many things, but the moment I remove the "Names" dimension from the table, it counts the total number of "Names" that match that "Option", not just the repeated ones

```
=Count([Name] In([Option];[Name])) In([Option])
```

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I have been working on this for a bit and have not figured anything out. Try posting your question [here](https://bobj-board.org/) or [here](https://answers.sap.com/index.html).